# Reference from return value to parameter

Tags: perl

Suppose we have a subroutine returning a reference

```
sub aspirin {
    my @items = qw(some items in here);
    return \@items;
}
```

And another subroutine taking an array reference

```
sub beetroot (\@) {
    my $lst = shift;
    print "$_\n" for @$lst;
}
```

I want to get the array from `aspirin` and feed `beetroot` with it. I would like to do something like (approach *A*)

```
my $L = aspirin;
beetroot $L;
```

But the interpreter complains, and I need to do the following instead (approach *B*):

```
my $L = aspirin;
beetroot @$L;
```

So my questions are:

- Why isn't the approach *A* working? The argument is actually an Array reference, which is what we want;
- Is a dereference without assignment (like the one in approach *B*) requiring the copy of the whole list content? (I guess not, since there's no explicit copy).

Thanks for your answers

Comment: This is item number one on the "List of Reasons Why You Don't Want Prototypes 99% of the Time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl prototypes exist to modify the behaviour of the parser, which is rarely needed. This is no exception.

If "`beetroot`" doesn't have any other arguments then you should just use `@_` instead of an array reference.

```
sub aspirin {
    my @items = qw'some items in here';
    return @items if wantarray; # return a list in list context
    return \@items;
}

sub beetroot {
    print "$_\n" for @_;
}

my $L = aspirin;
beetroot @$L;

# the follow examples require the version of aspirin from this answer

my @L = aspirin;
beetroot @L;

beetroot aspirin; # aspirin called in list context
```

This will have the added benefit that you don't have to work around the parser if you just want to input a list of elements.

This works on the new version, but not the version in the question.

```
beetroot qw'some items in here';
beetroot aspirin; # aspirin called in list context
```

To get it to work with the one in the question, you have to create an anonymous array. Interesting enough, this also works with the version in this answer.

```
beetroot @{ [qw'some items in here'] };
# the follow examples use the version of aspirin from this answer
beetroot @{ [aspirin] };
beetroot @{ scalar aspirin };
beetroot @{ aspirin };
```

---

If you really want "`beetroot`" to work with array references.
I would write it this way.

```
sub beetroot{
  my($lst) = @_; # similar to my $lst = shift
  print "$_\n" for @$lst;
}

my $L = aspirin;
beetroot $L;

my @L = aspirin; # using the aspirin from this answer
beetroot \@L;

beetroot [qw'some items in here'];
# the follow examples use the version of aspirin from this answer
beetroot scalar aspirin; # force aspirin to return an array reference
beetroot [ aspirin ]; # copy the array
```

I would only write it this way if you want to use references to reduce the memory footprint of Perl, or you have other inputs to "`beetroot`".

Answer (score 6):

The prototype `\@` does not mean array reference. It means give me an array, but I will get a reference to it as an argument (see `perldoc perlsub`.

Quote:

> Any backslashed prototype character represents an actual argument that
>   absolutely must start with that character.  The value passed as part
>   of `@_` will be a reference to the actual argument given in the
>   subroutine call, obtained by applying `"\"` to that argument.

Or, in other words, **do not use prototypes** unless you really know what they do.

Comment: On `perldoc perlsub` I can read: "the intent of this feature is primarily to let you define subroutines that work like built-in functions". As I can understand (correct me if I'm wrong) built-in functions differ from normal ones in the fact they can have side-effects, so I should use `\@` only when I want some side-effetcs on my array parameter. Is this correct?

Comment: Not correct; normal functions may have side-effects too. Instead, consider how to reimplement the call `push @a,@b`. If you call `my_push @a,@b`, your function will receive an array called `@_`, with no way to know where `@a` ends and `@b` begins. To fix this, you could call the sub with references (`my_push \@a,\@b` or `my_push \@a,@b`). Or with a prototype (`sub my_push (\@@) {...}`), you tell Perl to expect an array (not a list!) as the first argument to the function, and to pass it to your subroutine as an array reference, letting you say `my_push @a,@b` and having Perl do what you mean.